# Structuring state for a react/redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling with structuring a React/Redux application - I'm listing out the problem with options I tried for solutions, but nothing "feels right", so hoping someone here could help me out.

Here's a rough idea of my component structure:

```
<Dashboard>
    <Widget1 dataFetcher=()=>{}>
        <Header>
            <Title> ... </Title>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem {..cosmeticProps} text="OpenSettings" onClick=handleSettingsOpen>
                <MenuItem {..cosmeticProps} text="Delete" onClick=handleWidgetDelete>
            </Menu>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <Settings isOpen isValid fields onValidate onAutoComplete.. </Settings>
            { ifError ? ErrorLayout}
            { ifFetching ? FetchingLayout }
            { ifValid ? DataLayout }
        </Body>
    </Widget1>
    ...
</Dashboard>
```

And here's the state structure (event handlers shown for completeness, not because they're explicitly part of the state)

```
Dash: {
    widgets: {
        widget1: {
            menu: {
                isOpen: true,

                handleSettingsOpen: ()=>{}
                handleWidgetDelete: ()=>{}
            }
            settings: {
                isOpen: true,
                isValid: true,
                fields: [...],

                onValidate: ()=>{},
                onAutoComplete:()=>{},
                onSave:()=>{}
            }
            data: {
                isFetching: false,
                isError: false,
                items: [],

                fetch: ()=>{}
                parse: ()=>{}
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Option 1:**

Connect the dashboard and let it pass to children as required. i.e.,

Connected-dashboard.js

```
stateToProps ()=> { widgets: state.widgets }
dispatchToProps ()=> { handleSettingsOpen, handleWidgetDelete handleSettingsSave ... } //Dashboard would bind these with moduleid while rendering
```

- Pro: Everything else can be 'dumb', single source of truth
- Con: Knows too much about state, list of props/dispatches it takes just to pass down makes for ugly reading

**Option 2:**

Build a 'connected' widget and use that in the dashboard.

connected-widget.js

```
stateToProps ()=> { state.widgets[props.widgetid] }
dispatchToProps ()=> { handleSettingsOpen, handleWidgetDelete handleSettingsSave ... }
```

- Pro: Dashboard can now be a dumb container, which it is anyway
- Con: Widget knows too much about state structure?

**Option 3:**
Build connected versions of individual components and assemble later

connected-menu.js

```
stateToProps ()=> { state.widgets[props.widgetid].menu }
dispatchToProps ()=> { handleSettingsOpen, handleWidgetDelete }
```

connected-settings.js

```
stateToProps ()=> { state.widgets[props.widgetid].settings }
dispatchToProps ()=> { handleSave, handleValidate }
```

- Pro: Every component gets exactly the slice of state it cares about
- Con: Too many components listening on the state? Also the question of who 'assembles' it.

Option 3.1:
Restructure state to be:

```
Dashboard: {
    widgets: { ..}
    menu: {widgetid: {isopen ..}}
    settings: {widgetid: {widgetid ..}}
}
```

(State is flatter with this approach, but not sure if it matters much)

Overall, this may be naive/obvious, but to me the trade-off seems to be having a parent which either knows too much about the state, or too much about how it's children are put-together. How would you approach this?

Comment: re: option3, components don't listen to state, the store can _push_ updates itself, and you need not worry about having too many subscriptions

Comment: I agree option 3 is the best. Also always try to make your data structure as flat as possible. This is too nested `Dash: { widgets: { widget1: { menu: {`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - can you explain _why_ the nested structure is bad? with the nesting if later I need to delete a widget i can just remove it from the widgets structure; if it it was flat I need to clean it up from every other top-level item; what benefit would this provide?

Answer (score 0):

Option 3: Does it make sense for Menu and Settings to know "widgetId"? It seems they would be more reusable if they simply receive the properties menu or settings respectively.

Option 1: Do you want to update Dashboard stateToProps and dispatchToProps for each widget component supported?

For these reasons, I like option 2, the connected Widget1.

As for state nesting depth, [Redux Async Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) has a "Note on Nested Entities" that suggests avoiding deeply nested entities to avoid duplicate data.

In your example, if any widgets had duplicate menu or settings state object, a normalized state would allow the widgets to share the same state.

```
Dashboard: {
    widgets: {
        widget1: {menuId:1, settingsId: 1, ...},
        widget2: {menuId:1, settingsId: 1, ...},
    },
    menus: {1: {...}},
    settings: {1: {...}}
}
```

Actually, with this structure, Menu and Settings only need to know menuId or settingsId, not widgetId. I still prefer connecting the widget though.